# PHP/MySQL database question?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question I'm trying to have the q_id column take the value of the id column when a tag is submitted I have been trying to do this using PHP but I was thinking should I just add **AUTO INCREMENT** to the q_id column since but tables are updated when the tag is submited. or is this the wrong way to do it or is there a better way to do this?

Here is the MySQL tables below.

```
CREATE TABLE q_tags (
q_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
users_q_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: If you could give a little more description as to what your goals are with these tables that would really help in us providing a solution.

Comment: Basically the tables are for tags that users enter for there questions and then display them all for each individual question posted something like here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUTO INCREMENT is used mainly to avoid adding the same ID into a table, so that you can keep a loyal index. I'd suggest you add a primary key to the q_tags, and change the current q_id to a foreign key, so that it can become a reference to tags table.

EDIT :

```
CREATE TABLE q_tags (
q_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
t_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
users_q_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (q_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

t_id in the first table is the "foreign key". You can add it as a real mysql foreign key or just keep it this way (if you're planning on be able to "cascade delete" tags and t_tags related, it would matter)